# What are possible reasons for PC stops at the address of RET and does not move in LC3?

Tags: lc3

I used JSR and RET to jump to a subroutine and jump back to the main function. However, every time when the PC is on the address of RET, it stops there and never moves. Is there any possible reason for this problem? I did not use any subroutine inside my first subroutine, but I do use Branches. SO, I think my R7 does not change in the subroutine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any TRAPs? TRAP modifies R7 also.